# Swift: Force unwrap is nil and yet no crash...?

Tags: ios, swift, syntax

The Facebook SDK (4.x) has a delegate protocol that force unwraps the error that is returned.

```
extension FacebookLoginViewController: FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

        print("\(error)")

        if error == nil && result.isCancelled == false {
            //success
        }

    }

}
```

At runtime, when I cancel the login process, no error is returned and the above error pints nil. If the error value is nil then the force unwrap of the error parameter that is returned would surely result in a crash, no? Why doesn't this result in a crash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At no point in that code are you unwrapping `error`. Not even implicitly.

Since `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` conforms to `CustomStringConvertible`, the `print` function doesn't need to unwrap it. Instead, the print function calls the `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` implementation of `description` (which returns the string `"nil"`).

When you compare `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` to `nil`, Swift doesn't unwrap it. It treats it as a regular `Optional`. From [*The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2)*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html):

> You can still treat an implicitly unwrapped optional like a normal optional, to check if it contains a value:

Comment: You're right! `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional ` is also an `Optional`.Otherwise the compiler will warning you at `if error == nil ...`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but It just works like that:

```
let withoutCrash: String! = nil
withoutCrash


let withCrash: String? = nil
withCrash!
```

Comment: for what you answered if don't know))